# i just installed anaconda and i created a new environment and i'm trying to open jupyter notebook in this environment

Tags: python

i'm getting this error ;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2025, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 280, in launch_instance
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1051, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 575, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1311, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1354, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1330, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\Users\usatoleb\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

i tried uninstalling and installing it again, getting the same issue

Comment: I saw advice related to a post like your and so I'd suggest you try using conda-forge channel along with the conda command run inside your environment to install the latest complete set of related tech as suggested [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/issue-in-jupyter-notebook/21576/2?u=fomightez). If that doesn't help, maybe investigate further and update your post ....If you just open the Anaconda Navigator and use Jupyter via that in your base environment, does it work? If you get the same thing you are reporting there ...

Comment: <cotninued> , I'd suggest trying lowering the traitlets version, see https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/24436#issuecomment-1723328100 .